# Trying to rename files using 'os' module but getting errors

Tags: python, file, module, directory, rename

I am trying to rename files in my directory. I want to check if the file begins with a '000' then I will replace it with 'district' in the filename. So for example, filename "000_firstname_last_name" should be replaced with "district_firstname_lastname." But I am getting this error. I already checked if my directory was correct and it is. I will attach my code and screenshot of the error. Thanks.

```
import os
import shutil

# directory that needs to get sorted:
path = 'C:/Users/paulina.rios/Desktop/test'

# creates a list with directory file names
list = os.listdir(path)

# Goes through each file in the directory
for file in list:

    if file[0:3] == "000":
        split_file1 = file[3:]
        os.rename(file, "district" + split_file1)`
```

Here is the error: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77UwJ.png)

If the error image isn't working, I will copy paste it here:

```
File "C:\Users\paulina.rios\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2023.1\scratches\scratch.py", line 15, in <module>
    os.rename(file, "district" + split_file1)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: '000_11135_03220105_2016-2017.pdf' -> 'district_11135_03220105_2016-2017.pdf'
```

I double checked the folder location and it was correct.

Comment: `file` doesn't contain the directory path, it's just the filename. Use `os.path.join(path, file)`

Comment: And `os.path.join(path, "district" + split_file1)`